# How do you determine if Mac has a trackpad?

Tags: macos, trackpad

Does anyone know how to detect if a Mac has a trackpad input device?  There's got to be an easy way to detect this in code, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I wouldn't bet on there being an easy way.  You may need to fish around in the I/O Registry or parse `system_profiler` output.

Comment: Can you mention what you need this for? I can think of different approaches, but there's no 100% answer. Both a mouse and a trackpad could be attached, and depending on what you are trying to do, you might need this information on a per-mouse-event basis, or on a "is it attached" basis, or there might be a more precise system setting you can query instead of looking at the hardware.